# C-sharp Add-in button issues

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, installation, add-in

I have C# code for an Add-in button in ArcMap (10.8). An ArcGIS add-in would be built if no errors found in the C# code when building solutions. In the beginning, I resolved some errors by installing ArcObjects SDK (10.8) installation file. Then, a solution was built, with an add-in being rebuilt and added as a button to ArcMap. The issue is that when I click the button, there should be a user interface popping up in ArcMap since it was a part of the C# code. However, the user interface did not show up.

**How I attempted to address it:**
Then, I started debugging. I set a few breakpoints in the C# code. It turns out the C# code were never run to the point prior to the breakpoints that I set, which explains why the user interface did not show. Do you have a similar experience that can share with me?

**Where it might go wrong:**
I was wondering if the issue comes from the ArcObjects SDK file that I installed since I found that the ArcObjects SDK was installed in `C:\Program Files(x86)`.
Should the ArcObjects SDK be installed in `"Program Files"` instead of `"Program Files(x86)"`?

Another concern that I have is that should the ArcObjects SDK be in 64-bit because the computer system is also 64-bit? I assume the version of the ArcObjects SDK that I received is 64-bit, but not 100% sure.

Comment: No, ArcObjects for ArcMap 10.8 is 32-bit code (64-bit Pro has a different development tree). The `Program Files(x86)` is correct.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: It sounds like you've tried to retroactively build an addin, addins need to be created from the new project dialog then pick the Esri button dialog - that creates the template with the esriaddin file, after you have that you can hook your form to the click event but be sure to set your form MxDocument from your button IMxDocument or the link is lost. How are you debugging? Normally you set your target to 32 debug and have the debugger open ArcGIS or you code is not running so no breakpoints will be hit. ArcGIS for Desktop is still 32bit single thread, if you want 64bit then use ArcGIS Pro.